# The run tab at the bottom bar is missing on Android Studio Latest Version 4.0

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-studio-3.0, dart-pub

At the bottom the Run tab is missing. Please help me so that I don't waste more time on this trivial matter

[image]

Answer (score 3):

go to view -> tool window and then select run [here is the route]

Answer (score 0):

If you want see automatically the Run tab every time you run your app, you need to check the `Activate tool window`.

Steps:

1º - Click on Edit Configurations of your app
[image: Edit Configurations App Options]

2º - check the `Activate tool window`
[image: Activate Tool Window]